# Entropy Currents and their meaning

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

In [1] Callen derives the formula of the entropy production rate as a bilinear expression of currents and forces. Starting from the assumption of local equilibrium, that is, the Gibbs equation hold for the irreversible process, $TdS = \sum Y_kdX_k$, where $Y_k$ is the $k^{th}$ intensive variables conjugate to the extensive *and* conserved $X_k$, or $dS=\sum_k F_kdX_k$ with $F_k=Y_k/T$, and is assumed to hold for densities per unit volume: $$ds=\sum_kF_kdx_k \tag{1}\label{1}.$$
The conservation law for $x_k$ is $\frac{dx_k}{dt}=\dot x_k =0,$ that is $$\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial t} + \mathrm{div} \mathbf J_k=0 \tag{2}\label{2},$$ and for the entropy is $$\frac{ds}{dt}=\dot s= \frac{\partial s}{\partial t} + \mathrm{div} \mathbf J_s \tag{3}\label{3}.$$
Now multiply $\eqref{2}$ by $F_k$, sum and subtract the result from $\eqref{3}$ to get
$$\dot s= \sum_k \mathbf J_k \cdot \mathrm{grad}F_k + \mathrm {div}(\mathbf J_s - \sum_k F_k \mathbf J_k  )\tag{4}\label{4}.$$

Callen actually starts with the comment that from $\eqref{1}$ it is *reasonable* to assume that the entropy current $\mathbf J_s$  is defined by and thus equal to the sum $\sum_k F_k \mathbf J_s $ hence the entropy production rate is then the bilinear sum of the gradient of the forces $\mathrm {grad}F_k$ and currents $\mathbf J_k$:
$$\dot s= \sum_k \mathbf J_k \cdot \mathrm{grad}F_k\tag{5}\label{5}.$$
But if we look at $\eqref{4}$ we see that it is enough that the expression $\mathbf K = \mathbf J_s - \sum_k F_k \mathbf J_k$ be solenoidal, that is $\mathrm {div}\mathbf K=0$, or equivalently $$\mathbf K = \mathbf J_s - \sum_k F_k \mathbf J_k = \mathrm {curl}\mathbf A \tag{6}\label{6}$$ for some "vector potential" $\mathrm A$.

My question: Is it possible that $\mathbf K =\mathrm {curl}\mathbf A \ne 0$ and if so what is the physical meaning of $\mathbf {K,A}$, if any?

---

[1]: Callen THERMODYNAMICS AND AN INTRODUCTION TO THERMOSTATISTICS, Chapter 14, pp309-311